# NHibernate query help needed

Tags: t-sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Is it possible to convert the following query into ICriteria or LINQ, and if so, how?

```
    SELECT Test.personid
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT r.PersonId AS personid, e.ActivityId
        FROM Event e
        INNER JOIN Registration r ON e.Id = r.EventId
        WHERE e.ActivityId IN (1, 2)
        GROUP BY r.PersonId, e.ActivityId
    ) AS Test

    GROUP BY Test.personid
    HAVING COUNT(Test.ActivityId) >= 2
```

Comment: the query will always return nothing. the inner query does returns `nothing` or `activityId 1` or `activityId 2` or `activityId 1 and 2` for every personid then count over it which is max 2 and then filter out all max 2

Comment: Yes, thats true. I did some manual name changing after i posted it here, so it seems i removed one of the activity id's, because it was supposed to be 3. I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from r in session.Query<Registration>()
             where r.Event.ActivityId == 1 || r.Event.ActivityId == 2
             group r by r.Person into g
             where g.Min(x => x.Event.ActivityId) != g.Max(x => x.Event.ActivityId)
             select g.Key
```

the following states, take all Persons wich have different activityIds in there groups which is equivalent to

```
ActivityId == 1 || ActivityId == 2
Having Count(r.Event.ActivityId) >= 2
```